# Как запретить скролл не ставя overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как оставить полосу прокрутки и при этом запретить скролл на странице? Открывается модалка, и при этом, чтобы не было скролла всему html, который выше в несколько раз окна браузера, добавляется overflow:hidden, но при этом получается эффект прыгания по горизонтали из за того что полоса прокрутки то появляется, то исчезает. Как запретить скролл фона модалки не добавляя overflow:hidden, то есть оставив полосу прокрутки?

```css
html{
 position:relative;
 margin:0 auto;
 /*overflow:hidden; - не нужно использовать*/
 height:100vh;
 width:100%;
}
html body:after{
 content:'';
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:9;
}
modal {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 25;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 18.75rem;
    right: 0;
    padding: 4.125rem 1rem 1rem;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<modal>modal</modal>
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
```

UPD: Должна остаться функция скролла внутри модалки. И нельзя потерять позицию в основном контенте при открытии модалки, поэтому position:fixed не подходит.

Comment: а в тот момент когда модалка открылась можно же для боди убрать скролл на js ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

position: sticky;

```css
html {
  position: sticky;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*overflow:hidden; - не нужно использовать*/
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

html body:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

modal {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 25;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 18.75rem;
  right: 0;
  padding: 4.125rem 1rem 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<modal>modal</modal>
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>1
<br>2
<br>3
```

Comment: Почти то, что нужно! Но при открытии модалки скроллит на топ, хоть и при закрытии возвращается обратно. Но скачок тоже не очень приятный, заметен глазу. Разве что из js запоминать позицию теперь?

Comment: kizoso,  без js точно не обойтись... прости, я с планшета... подробнее не могу...))))

Comment: ксстати, за столько лет практики ыпервые вижу псевдо элемент ***HTML BODY***... Откуда такая фантазия?)))))

Comment: Добавляю js `var htmlPosition = $('html').scrollTop();$('html').css('top', -htmlPosition).addClass('slide-is-open');` при скролле вниз все прекрасно при скролле наверх артефакты, пытается прилипать но не выходит

Comment: HTML BODY)) это я не внимательно код обрезала похоже)) конечно такого нет) просто сам кусок кода большой пыталась максимально обрезать, и видимо недоглядела  случайно html добавила

Comment: артефакты в FF ubuntu, в хроме все ок

Comment: написала js, в случае открытой модалки, слушаю скролл и проскролливаю до якоря который был при ее открытии

Comment: `var listenScroll = false;
function scroller(ancor) {
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        if (ancor!==-1 && listenScroll === true) {
            window.scrollTo({
                top: ancor,
                behavior: "instant"
            });
        } else {
            return false
        }
    });
}`

Comment: Рад, что сработало...